# Setting up XAMPP to run python script on mac

Tags: macos, xampp, python-3.4

I googled this and tried everything but I could not run my test.py on apache.
I have updated httpd.conf file to AddHandler .py

URL I'm using is http://localhost/cgi-bin/test.py

test.py

```
#!/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4 python

print("Content-Type: text/html");
print();
print("<html><head></head><body>");
print ("Hello");
print("</body></html>");
```

I am not sure if the shebang line is correct or not, but that is where I've installed python.

When I open this file in browser I am getting this error

```
Error message: 
End of script output before headers: test.py
```

Please suggest, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After going back and forth, I did this in terminal

```
which python
```

And I got path for my exe

```
#!/Library/Frameworks/anaconda/bin/python
```

I used this and my script worked, hope this helps to someone else too.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that is a correct path to your python installation? By default it should be something like

```
#!/Python27/python
```

Comment: that is where I installed python 3.4.3, I got that path from get info on mac